# How do I replace a character between the last occurrence of two characters in a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, textbox

I have an input text field named `d[hotel][suite][0]`. How would I replace the last `[0]` with `[1]` or `[2]` and so on? Is this possible using jQuery or would I have to use the replace function with regex?

What I've tried so far:

```
the_name = $(this).attr('name');
the_name = the_name.replace(/[.*]/, '2');
```

Didn't work

```
the_name = $(this).attr('name');
var start_pos = the_name.lastindexOf('[') + 1;
var end_pos = the_name.lastindexOf(']',start_pos);
var text_to_replace = the_name.substring(start_pos,end_pos);
```

Doesn't work with 2+ digits.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try ? can you give more explanations ?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any fancy string-processing functions AFAIK.

Comment: @shafeen His input is `d[hotel][suite][0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably easier using a regexp.

```
new_name = the_name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]$/, function(match, n) {
    return '[' + (parseInt(n, 10)+1) + ']');
});
```

The `$` anchor in the regexp makes it match the brackets at the end. When you use a function as the replacement, it calls the function with the matched string and each of the capture groups as arguments, and whatever it returns is used as the replacement.

Comment: It unfortunately returns `01`, `11`, `111`, `1111`, and so on.

Comment: Fixed it, needed some parentheses.